# maven resources does not copy anything to .properties file

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to use `maven-resources-plugin` to copy properties from maven profiles onto the application properties file but with no luck, and i cant find what i am missing for it to work

I have in my pom.xml:

> ```
> <profiles>
>     <profile>
>         <id>development</id>
>         <activation>
>             <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
>         </activation>
>         <properties>
>             <profile.Amazon.S3.accessKeyId>123</profile.Amazon.S3.accessKeyId>
>             <profile.Amazon.S3.secretAccessKey>123</profile.Amazon.S3.secretAccessKey>
>         </properties>
>     </profile>
>     <profile>
>         <id>production</id>
>         <properties>
>             <profile.Amazon.S3.accessKeyId>456</profile.Amazon.S3.accessKeyId>
>             <profile.Amazon.S3.secretAccessKey>4567</profile.Amazon.S3.secretAccessKey>
>         </properties>
>     </profile>
> </profiles>
> ```

AND:

```
    <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

my properties file:

> Amazon.S3.accessKeyId=${profile.Amazon.S3.accessKeyId}
>   Amazon.S3.secretAccessKey=${profile.Amazon.S3.secretAccessKey}

when running the application (does not matter if i specify a profile or not) i always get an error from spring on this line:

```
private @Value("${Amazon.S3.accessKeyId}") String S3_ACCESS_KEY;

 Could not resolve placeholder 'profile.Amazon.S3.accessKeyId' in string value "${profile.Amazon.S3.accessKeyId}"
```

Comment: First, is it a Maven problem, or a Spring configuration problem? Check what the properties file contains in `target/classes`. If the property has been replaced, it's not a Maven problem, but a SPring config problem.

Comment: its not been replaced its left with the "${profile.Amazon.S3.accessKeyId} "